# What is the practical limit on the number of classes one can have in java program file?

Tags: java, class

What is the practical limit on the number of classes one can have in java program file? Is it necessary for the classes defined inside a file to have the same name as the name of the file?

Comment: First, no limit. Second : yes it is necessary

Comment: Define practical. @BillBilal "no limit" - until your storage fills up.

Comment: As much as the capacity of your computers' memory.

Comment: Your compiler needs to be able to compile the file in one go.  This is likely to be your limiting factor and it is likely to be far higher than what is a sane number for you to write and maintain. e.g. the JDK src.zip has only about 8K classes.